# glob (star) operator, method disappearing, Perl

Tags: perl, glob

I have a module which is giving me the error "Can't locate object method "isSubset" via package "a" (perhaps you forgot to load "a"?) at /path/to/set.pm line 121.

SET.PM:

```
package set; #we will create set objects, instead of treating arrays as sets

sub new{
    my $packagename = shift;
    my @elements = @_;
    bless { 'elements' => \@elements } => $packagename;
}

sub contains{
    my $set = shift;
    my ($element) = @_;
    foreach ($set->elements){ if( $_ eq $element ){ return 1 } }
    return 0
}
sub isElement{
    my ($element,$set) = @_;
    return $set->contains($element)
}

sub isSubset{
    my $setA = shift;
    my $setB = shift;
    foreach ($setA->elements){ unless( isElement($_,$setB) ){ return 0 } }
    return 1
}
*subset = *isContainedIn = *isContained = \&isSubset;
sub isSuperset{
    my $setA = shift;
    my $setB = shift;
    return $setB->isSubset($setA) # this is line 121
}
*superset = *isContaining = *contains = \&isSuperset; # when i get rid of THIS line, it works fine.
```

When I comment out the last line, it works fine.  Can you enlighten me on what is causing the failure?  Am I using glob incorrectly?

CALLING PROGRAM:

```
my $a = set->new('a'..'g');
my $b = set->new('b'..'f');
print $a->isSubset($b);
```

Comment: The variable $setB has the value "a". Your sample code doesn't show how you call the sub, so we can't help you further.

Comment: The variable $setB does not have the value "a", and the CALLING PROGRAM shows exactly how I call the sub.  Please be more explanatory if you are sure you are correct.

Comment: @choroba $a, which becomes $setA, has the value 'a'

Comment: OK, now you call `'a'->isSubset()`. As `'a'` is not an object, it's interpreted as a class name. Hence the error.

Comment: @choroba if you know the issue, please post an Answer which explains it clearly.  Also explain why commenting out the bottom line gets rid of the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turn on `warnings`. Perl will tell you:

```
Subroutine set::contains redefined at ./1.pl line 44.
```

You use `contains` for testing both an element and a set.